# How do I for an error in node-modules twitter-api-v2?

Tags: reactjs, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I'm trying to use the twitter api in a React class component. Im getting an error coming from the node-modules.

Heres my code:

This is not the final version. I use it to test.

```
import { TwitterApi } from "twitter-api-v2"
//const { TwitterApi } = require("twitter-api-v2");

const client = new TwitterApi({
    
});

const rwClient = client.readWrite;


export default function Twitter() {
    const textTweet = async () => {
        try {
          await rwClient.v2.tweet(
              "This tweet has been created using nodejs");
          console.log("success");
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
    };
    
    const mediaTweet = async () => {
        try {
          const mediaId = await client.v1.uploadMedia("../assets/lion.png");
          await rwClient.v2.tweet({
                text: "Lmao",
                media: { media_ids: [mediaId] },
          });
          console.log("success");
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
    };

    return(
        <button className="button" onClick={textTweet}>Tweet</button>
    )
}
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E87J8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmmoK.png)

I want to call my component ans tweet using that component

Comment: Looks like the problem is in `TweetStreamEventCombiner` and it trying to extend `EventEmitter`. Is there any more detailed error from the IDE? Doesn't look like a Twitter/X API issue at this point anyway. Maybe some other pieces of code should appear in the question(?)